# pytorch based Flask app image exits after running

Tags: docker, tensorflow, dockerfile, huggingface-transformers

I used pytorch ran a ML model and used flask created an app. Everything works fine on my local machine as well as on server. Newly learnt docker image and wish to pack everything in. I have mac and installed docker desktop. With numerous attempts and configurations the container based on the image i created stops after finish running the py code.

Code for setting up the dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.9-stretch
RUN apt-get update
WORKDIR  /usr/src/App
COPY requirements.txt . 
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN ls -la .
CMD ["python3", "app.py", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]
```

code for building the image:

```
docker build -t app:v1 .
```

code for running the container:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 app:v1
```

in my py file, i also specified:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8000, debug=True)
```

After the code finish running, the container exits.

I looked at the log file, there's seemingly some error, but I don't think that causes anything as it also says after the error that if i'm using gpu then i can ignore it (i am not using gpu)

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 0):

1. To solve error from logs. I would suggest to try to remove all python images on host and check that all builded layers ware erased too, than try to use different minor version of image. Let's say python:3.7.10-stretch from [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/python). Your code from example definitely couldn't produce such error, sometimes some images are just broken by updates of software that they use. In this case some compiled soft used by python looks corrupted.
2. To container exit. Try to change last line to `CMD ["python3", "app.py"]` and pass params as [environment](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file). You should be ok at this point. But I would recommend to dig dipper into docker, this image needs some tuning.

Big picture here how CMD works - [Entrypoint & cmd difference and how it works](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-2-create-a-dockerfile) you may find a good example of flask and docker

Comment: Thank you, I tried your point2 but it didn't work either. I tried both Entrypoint and cmd, the issue remained the same. container stops right after finish running py file.

Comment: Ok, pls share full command that you run to start docker container and app.py

Comment: Thanks @Rkm, after numerous trying I finally got on, but still with some mystery, I just put my findings below, please kindly provide some thoughts. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by removing debug=True in my .py file. After that, the container no longer exits after running the .py file.

I also found the "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000" that I put in the Dockerfile shown as below has no use at all. Having them in the code or not had no impact at all. Maybe someone can kindly point out why in some online cases people write them in their CMD command?

`CMD ["python3", "app.py", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]`

Also another interesting fact occured was when I ran:

`App % docker run -p 6000:8000 app:v1`

The port 6000 on my mac computer cannot open the page. But if I try other ports on my mac, the page will show. This also occurred when I tried 8000:8000 at the beginning. However, after me worked on solving other issues, the port 8000 on my mac magically worked by itself for mysterious reason. Maybe someone could kindly provide me some ideas on what's happening here as well.

Comment: CMD ["python3", "app.py", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]  means: Python run application app.py and pass the --host and the --port parameters to that application. It is up to your app.py to do something with those parameters. If your app does not process those flags,  then you do not need to add them to the CMD.

Comment: thank you @camba1, is the --port=8000 in CMD above a port on local host machine or a port inside docker?
in my py code i had app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8000). When should i assign port in py code vs assign port in dockerfile CMD?

Comment: I just opened another question, @ camba1 plz feel free to answer there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66269187/assigning-port-when-building-flask-docker-image