# Assigning port when building flask docker image

Tags: docker, flask, docker-image

I recently created an app using flask and put the py file in a docker container. However I am confused with online cases where people assigned the port.

First of all on the bottom of my py file I wrote

`if __name__ == "__main__":`

`app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8000, debug=True)`

In some cases I saw people specify the port in CMD when making dockerfile

```
CMD ["python3", "app.py", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]
```

In my own experience, the port assigned in CMD didn't work on my case at all. I wish to learn the differences between the two approaches and when to use each way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding this approach:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8000, debug=True)
```

`__name__` is equal to `"__main__"` when the app is launched directly with the `python` interpreter (executed with the command `python app.py`) - which is a python technicallity and nothing to do with Flask.  In that case the `app.run` function is called, and it accepts the various arguments as stated.  `app.run` causes the Werkzeug development server to run.

This block will *not* be run, if you're executing the program with a production WSGI server like `gunicorn` as `__name__` will not be equal to `"__main__"` in that case, so the `app.run` call is bypassed.

In practice, putting the `app.run` call in this `if` block means you can run the dev server with `python app.py` and avoid running the dev server when the same code is imported by `gunicorn` or similar in production.

---

There are lots of older tutorials or posts which reference the above approach.  Modern versions of Flask ship with the `flask` command which is intended to replace this.  So essentially **without that `if` block**, you can launch the development server which imports your app object in a similar manner to to `gunicorn`:

`flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8000`

This automatically looks for an object called `app` in `app.py`, and accepts the host and port options, as you can see from `flask run --help`:

```
Options:
  -h, --host TEXT                 The interface to bind to.
  -p, --port INTEGER              The port to bind to.
```

One advantage of this method is that the development server won't crash if you're using the auto reloader and introduce syntax errors.  And of course the same code will be compatible with a production server like `gunicorn`.

---

With the above in mind, regarding the command you pass:

```
python app.py --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

I'm not sure if you've been confused with references to the `flask` command's supported options, but for this one to work you'd need to manually write some code to do something with those options.  This could be done with a python module like `argparse`, but that would probably be redundant given that the `flask` command actually supports this out of the box.

To conclude: you should probably remove the `if` block, and your Dockerfile should contain:

```
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]
```

You may also wish to check the `FLASK_ENV` environment variable [is set](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) to `development` to use the auto reloader, and be aware that the `CMD` line would need to be changed within this Dockerfile to run with `gunicorn` or similar in production, but that's probably outwith the scope of this question.

Comment: make lots of sense to me, thank you very much, indeed i was confused and mixing things here @v25

Comment: I also checked the sources i was reading @v25, it was clear that none of them writing CMD[python app.py --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000], it was me mixing thing up...my bad, again thank you so much for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @MeiNanZhu Glad I could help.  I wanted to expand on the last part more.  If you make it as far as using docker compose you may wish to see my repo [flask-reload-in-docker](https://github.com/vulcan25/flask-reload-in-docker) which is my take on supporting both dev and prod with compose file overides, and a single Dockerfile for both.  Any queries about that feel free to log an issue against the repo.

Comment: Thank you @v25. I experienced another mystery that I posted in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250745/pytorch-based-flask-app-image-exits-after-running
In short, when I had app.run(debug=True), the container runs my py file and exits right after. However, after I took off debug=True, container doesn't exit any longer (which is what I need, so I can access the app through IP). Do you by chance understand the reason behind. Many thanks.

Comment: Well explained @v25. When I `docker run -it -p 5001:5001` an image build with a Dockerfile including `ENTRYPOINT flask run -h "..." -p ...`, Flask (inside the container) states to be `running on all addresses (0.0.0.0), http://127.0.0.1:5001 and http://172.17.0.2:5001`. Browsing to 127.0.0.1:5001 on host is succesful, and I can `nmap` the two addresses from inside the container. But why is Flask running on two ip-addresses inside the container?

Answer (score 1):

`CMD ["python3", "app.py", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]` means: Python run application app.py and pass the --host and the --port parameters to that application. It is up to your app.py to do something with those parameters. If your app does not process those flags, then you do not need to add them to the CMD.

If in your code you have `app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8000)`,  then your app will always be listening to port 8000 inside the container. In this case you can just use `CMD ["python3", "app.py"]`

If you wanted to have the ability to change the port and host that your app is listening to, the you could add some code to read the values from the command line. Once you setup your app to look at values from the command line, then it would make sense to run `CMD ["python3", "app.py", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]`

Comment: Good answer.  I've given another one which kind of adds to the (correct) points you have made.

Answer (score 0):

## I made the following changes in my flask application and it started working.

### Flask Application:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000, debug=True)
```

### Dockerfile:

```
# Base image
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install dependencies
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the application code
COPY . .

# Expose the application port
EXPOSE 5000

# Start the application
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```